# Share app's data on social networking sites

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I am trying share my app's data in social networking sites.i am trying to implement sharekit but i encountered a lot of errors.Is there a way other than sharekit to share my app to social networking sites atleast to facebook and twitter?

Comment: You can implement your own integration with facebook and twitter by using their APIs directly, however, that can be a lot of work.  I have successfully used ShareKit with good success.  Are you sure you are using the latest version of [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) and carefully followed the [installation instructions](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit)?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to target Twitter and Facebook it's also worth looking into the iOS Social Framework.

Note that Facebook is only supported as of iOS6, but this api is far simpler in use than the other solutions for user handling, posting, etc...

You can find a lot of good tutorials on this topic (ex. http://www.raywenderlich.com/21558/beginning-twitter-tutorial-updated-for-ios-6)